# What is an equivalent for the word "alas"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, interjections

What is an appropriate translation for the word "alas" in the following sentence: "Alas, I am not available until a future date".

I have seen two expressions, Hélas, and malheureusement (which I understand to mean sadly).

I want to fully encompass the richness and the somewhat humorous grief that it has come to express in English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither English, nor French native but I believe that *hélas* is the counterpart of "alas". [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%A9las) says

> From Old French elas, variant of a las, from a (“ah”) + las, from
>   Latin lassus (“weary”).

I believe thus that English "alas" and French *hélas* are like brother and sister.
For further examples see here:

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/h%C3%A9las

I would translate your sentence as:

> Hélas, je ne serai pas disponible avant une date ultérieure.

**EDIT**

1) Based on @aCOSwt's comment:

They (i.e. alas and hélas) are not exactly as brother and sister. Alas cannot be used as a noun while hélas can be used as a noun (since the XVth century).

2) Based on @D. Ben Knoble's comment:

Hélas seems in more current usage in France than alas does in (American) English.

3) Extension of (2); comparison of alas and hélas frequency:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alas&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calas%3B%2Cc0

American English (even lower)

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alas&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calas%3B%2Cc0

French

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=h%C3%A9las&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ch%C3%A9las%3B%2Cc0

**EDIT 2**

In the Greek language there is the world [pheû](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%86%CE%B5%CF%85). It means hélas. It would be interesting to see any connection between the etymology of hélas and the pheû.

Comment: You are correct. Apart from your *like brother and sister*... What they are not exactly. As far as I know, *Alas* cannot be used as a noun while *Hélas* can be used as a noun since the XVth century.

Comment: Also, _hélas_ seems in more current usage in France than _alas_ does in American English

Comment: @aCOSwt do you have an example of "hélas" used as a noun ? For me it is primarily an interjection and its use like a noun is more like an exception.

Comment: @radouxju : You are correct : Hélas! is indeed primarily an interjection. However, quoting phrases like "*Il fit de grands hélas. Voyez le bel hélas.*" The *Dictionnaire de l'Académie Française* , (5th-8th editions) states that *"Il s'emploie quelquefois, familièrement, comme substantif." You can also view the frequency of such usage here : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=h%C3%A9las_NOUN&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ch%C3%A9las_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bh%C3%A9las_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BH%C3%A9las_NOUN%3B%2Cc0